# Rails link with error message and current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have hard time coming up with an idea how to implement a link called "Add guide", that requires user to be signed in. To direct to new guide path I need to add "new_user_guide_path(@user) or "new_user_guide_path(current_user)", and adding "current_user" or @user causes an error because of being equal nil - so I don't know how to implement new method in guide controller. 
PS: I used devise gem to create user model.
my header partial:

```
<header class="cf header2">
    <h1 class="logo"><%= link_to "E-LEARN", root_path %></h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <% unless user_signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "My Account", current_user %></li>
        <% end %>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Add tutorial", new_user_guide_path(@user) %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

and routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:show, :index, :new] do
    resources :guides
  end

  authenticated :user do
    root to:  'users#dashboard', as: "authenticated_root"
  end

  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

Error message:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-23 23:25:13 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"guides", :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_id]):
    10:           <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
    11:           <li><%= link_to "My Account", current_user %></li>
    12:         <% end %>
    13:           <li><%= link_to "Add tutorial", new_user_guide_path(current_user) %></li>
    14:       </ul>
    15:     </nav>
    16:   </header>
  app/views/shared/_header.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_shared__header_html_erb__869860312033883396_70024564174000'
  app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_devise_sessions_new_html_erb___1648951009615067685_70024756409300'
```

And after I changed to current_user.id:

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

So basically current user is nil when there is no logged in user - no big suprise. But is there any way to get around this error thanks to some before_filters or before_action and include link to adding guuide that requires logged in user data without user being actually logged in?

Comment: can you post the error msg please

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
`<% if signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to "Profile", profile_path %>
  <% if can? :update, @user %>
    <%= link_to "Admin", admin_root_path %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
 <% else %>
   <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
   <%= link_to "Join Us", new_user_registration_path %>
 <% end %>`
```

And change your

`current_user.id` to `current_user`

This worked for me ,hope it will do same for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add "Add tutorial" link in else condition:-

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "My Account", current_user %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Add tutorial", new_user_guide_path(current_user) %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

Add before_filter in guide controller:-

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```